# Calculate the following determinant:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to calculate the determinant of the following matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha +\beta&\alpha\beta&0&\cdots&0&0\\
1&\alpha + \beta &\alpha \beta&\cdots&0& 0\\
0&1&\alpha + \beta & \cdots &0&0\\
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&1&\alpha + \beta\end{pmatrix}$$

Here is my attempt

[image]

Is this correct?

I used Laplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we have that

$$D_n=(\alpha+\beta)D_{n-1}-\alpha\beta D_{n-1}$$

and then we can proceed by recurrence with

- $D_1=\alpha+\beta$
- $D_2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-\alpha\beta$

Answer (score 0):

The matrices satisfy the recurrence relation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta_n=( \alpha+\beta) \Delta_{n-1}-\alpha \beta \Delta_{n-2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It easy to show by induction that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}  \alpha^{i}\beta^{n-i}=  \frac{\alpha^{n}- \beta^{n}}{\alpha- \beta}.
\end{eqnarray*}